# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table tags has no column named 0

Tags: laravel, sqlite

I'm trying to seed data into tags table my schema is as follows:

```
Schema::create('tags',function (Blueprint $table){
           $table->bigIncrements('id');
           $table->string('tag_name');
        });
```

my seed is as follows:

```
public function run()
    {
        $array=array(
            array(
                'computer'
            ),
            array(
                'hp'
            ),
            array(
                'mac'
            )


        );
        DB::table('tags')->insert($array);
    }
```

Comment: you would need to have the inner arrays have keys matching the field in the database you are assigning the value to, `tag_name`

Comment: could you please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array of data to insert into the database is an associative array where the keys are the columns to be set with corresponding values:

```
['field' => $value, 'other_field' => $otherValue]
```

If you bulk inserting you will have an array containing arrays of values to insert:

```
[['tag_name' => 'computer'], ['tag_name' => 'hp'], ...]
```

Currently you have zero indexed arrays:

```
[[0 => 'computer'], [0 => 'hp'], ...]
```

So it is trying to set a column named `0`.

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Query Builder - Inserts](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#inserts)